# Typescript conditional function signature - based on boolean in option

Tags: javascript, typescript

Edited with partial function implementation that seems relevant:

I have this function:

```js
mergeArrayElement<T>(
  array: T[],
  element: T | PartialDeep<T>,
  options?: {
    overwriteMerge?: boolean
  }
) {
  const index = list.findIndex(...);
  if (index > -1) {
    if (options.overwriteMerge) {
      list[index] = element; // type error can't assign PartialDeep<T> to T.
    } else {
      list[index] = deepmerge(list[index],element);
    }
  }
}
```

This function takes an element of `partial type T`, finds the target element in the array with some irrelevant logic, and merges it.

I want this function to have an option, that does the same thing, but instead of merging it just overwrites the element, I call it `overwriteMerge` but in reality, there is no merging done with it.

I want that when options `overwriteMerge` is given as true, the element will be required and type-checked to be `T` (and recognized as such in the function by typescript), And when `overwriteMerge` is false (or not given) then the element will have to be `PartialDeep<T>`.

Is such a thing possible with typescript or do I need another function? If I'm just regular merging the elements I'm okay with the object just being a partial type of the objects in the list. But If I'm simply overriding the element in the array, I want it to be the exact same type of array.

Comment: Please add the implementation done for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Method Overloading](https://learntypescript.dev/05/l3-overloading)

*For the seek of example `DeepPartial` has been replaced with `Partial`*

```js
function mergeArrayElement<T>(array: T[], element: T, options?: { overwriteMerge?: true });
function mergeArrayElement<T>(array: T[], element: Partial<T>, options?: { overwriteMerge?: false });
function mergeArrayElement<T>(
    array: T[],
    element: T | Partial<T>,
    options?: { overwriteMerge?: boolean }
) {
    if (options?.overwriteMerge) {
        // implementation 1
    } else {
        // implementation 2
    }
}
```

This will result in

```
type X = { a: number, b: number };
mergeArrayElement<X>([], { a: 1, b: 2 }, { overwriteMerge: true })
mergeArrayElement<X>([], { a: 1 }, { overwriteMerge: true }) // invalid
mergeArrayElement<X>([], { a: 1, b: 2 }, { overwriteMerge: false })
mergeArrayElement<X>([], { a: 1 }, { overwriteMerge: false })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't know method overloading exists, I didn't have enough info before in the post but I edited the implementation too, it works perfectly for validating correct function call, but I need to somehow inside the function implementation to understand the type of `element` based on `options.overwriteMerge`.

Comment: @user3575645 a simple if will not work?

Comment: From my quick test typescript didn't seem to infer that if `options.overwriteMerge === true`, then `element` is necessarily `<T>` inside this `if` from this overloading. I'll test it again soon to see if I implemented it incorrectly or missed something.

Comment: Not clear what are you attempting to do. Typescript will not infer, you still need to pass `{ overwriteMerge: true }` as a parameter.

Comment: I'm talking about the function implementation, not related to invoking the function, so parameters aren't passed. Inside the function implementation, I put 
`If ( options.overwriteMerge ) {console.log(element) }`

But if I hover over `element`, typescript tells me it's of type `T | PartialDeep<T>`. Even though if the function were to be invoked, and I did pass `{overwriteMerge: true}` and get into this `if` statement, element will necessarily be `T`. But typescript doesn't infer that.

Comment: The Implementation Signature (the actual signature) must match all other signatures. But the signatures are still soft types, so within the `if` you will need to assert it with `element as T` & `element as Partial<T>`